# ArrayList not reading in properly

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList & I Want it to read in & Total the numbers within the file, but it is only outputting the last number within the file, they are all on different lines etc.

```
Here is my code, thanks in advance: 

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListOfNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner (new File("numbers.txt"));

        int sumOf = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
            sumOf = sumOf + list.get(i);
        }
        //while scanning add sum to ArrayList List
        while (Scan.hasNext())
        {
            sumOf = Scan.nextInt();
            list.add(sumOf);
        }
        //print the array list
        System.out.println(sumOf);
        Scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're summing up the numbers in the list before you read the numbers.

So move your loop like this:

```
    //while scanning add sum to ArrayList List
    while (Scan.hasNext())
    {
        int number = Scan.nextInt();
        list.add(number);
    }
    int sumOf = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
        sumOf = sumOf + list.get(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing `sumOf` not the list. Of course that is a single number.

Also you should read the numbers before summing them.

Answer (score 0):

Read line by line, appropriately name variables. After you read from the file, iterate over the list and sum.

```
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
 }
```